# Is it a big "No" to have numbers in your professional / work email address?

Tags: professionalism, email

I'm trying to create an email address which I use for job applications. I'm using Gmail because I don't think I have enough money to buy my own domain (as I've seen suggested on other websites).

I don't have a middle name. Assume my first name is William and my last name is Wilson. william.wilson@gmail.com and wilson.william@gmail.com are both already taken. will.wilson, william.wils, w.wilson, w.william, ww.wiliam, ww.wilson, william.ww.wilson are all taken as well (ww is for my initials).

I feel like I'll have to use numbers for my work email address (w.wilson02@gmail.com is not taken yet).

Do note though that I tried william_wilson@outlook.com and it is not taken yet either, but I've read articles saying that underscores are not professional and should not be used in a work email.

Comment: I have them in mine (along with my full name), it's perfectly acceptable :)

Comment: @JaneS I think it's acceptable but it does breed a question of professionalism. I know it shouldn't, but it does to me, and if it does to me I can imagine that it would to some others as well.

Comment: @zfrisch So you would not hire someone because they had a number in their email address?  I would have issues if it was something lame, stupid or inappropriate, but honestly, you look at it once or twice during the hiring process, and it's done with.

Comment: @JaneS Sorry, I didn't explain well enough. If I receive an e-mail from someone and their e-mail is first.last035@domain.com I may be a little put off by the validity of the e-mail when browsing my inbox. It's not the end of the world and I wouldn't avoid hiring someone. As a preference though, with numbers or without, I would prefer without as it's simple, clean, professional looking and easy to remember. You're right though. It's a preference and it's not a deal-breaker BUT if at all possible I would strive for one without numbers.

Comment: I have had some issues explaining underscores to foreigners, so that's probably a good call. I don't use numbers like that because they lack meaning and are hard to remember, but not because I think it affects people's views of me professionally, it really doesn't matter all that much.

Comment: @zfrisch I have a similar view point.  I also am aware that sometimes it's just not possible, especially with "portable" email addresses such as GMail.

Comment: Domains cost next to nothing - the most expensive one I have is less than $20 every year.

Comment: @HorusKol True, but it just postpones the problem... eventually all the domains that look reasonably close to common names will run out too.

Comment: @JuliaHayward why does the domain have to be a common name? Mine isn't, but then you can put whatever you want before the @ in an email ;)

Comment: Domains are inexpensive, but if you want to avoid that route, perhaps invent a middle name? If you have a confirmation name or similar, you could use that, or borrow from a beloved relative, like JK Rowling did.

Comment: @zfrisch Would your suspicion change if it was just  single digit, say, ssharpe2@foo.com - Offices sometimes adopt a similar naming scheme if there is more than one "S. Sharpe" in the employee roster.

Comment: @HorusKol It doesn't have to be, just that people with common names will be the first to discover they can't get a domain which is reasonably close to their name, same as they can't get a gmail account like that